# Kubuntu: Change proxy settings from console

Tags: kubuntu, kde, proxy

I want to change proxy in whole system. I am using Kubuntu 14.04 64bit.

I know that should change proxy variables like ***http_proxy="http://proxy.xxx.xx:80XX/"*** etc.

But it will not change proxy in KDE settings, so I have to do it manually in Settings GUI, but I want to write one command and change proxy for whole system.

Does exist something similar as ***gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy*** for KDE? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your:

```
gedit /etc/profile
```

Enter the details in this format.

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

Comment: how you do it on-the-fly ? like changing in control center ?